# Hartshorne Exercise II 6.3 (d)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem is the following:

> Let V be a projective variety in $\mathbb P^n$ of dimension $\ge 1$ and nonsingular in codimension $1$, and let $X=C(V)\in \mathbb A^{n+1}$ be the affine cone. Set $P=(X_0,\cdots,X_n)$ be the vertex of the cone.
>
> (d) Let $\mathcal O_P$ be the local ring of $P$ on $X$.Show that the natural restriction map induces an isomorphism $\operatorname{Cl} X\to \operatorname{ClSpec}(\mathcal O_P)$.

The surjectivity is obvious, but I don't know how to show the injectivity. It seems that I need to show any prime $Q\nsubseteq P $ of ht 1 form a principal divisor. But I have no idea...